# Trying to install ubuntu in primary partion .but converting logical to primary makes some problem

Tags: boot

Actually mine is Lenovo z580 and in my laptop already 2 os are installed i.e Windows 7, Windows 8 and I want to install Ubuntu but it's not installing and two primary partitions are there and trying to one disk logical to primary and it is showing that "there is no free slot is available in MBR".

Comment: You forgot to attach the image link :P

Answer (score 0):

On an mbr you can only have 3 primary partitions and one extended partition (containing logical partitons) or 4 primary partitions. In windows 7 I believe it may make a partition for boot if its installed first. Its also possible that you just need to shrink down one or both your partition’s to make free space.